# ggplotly hover label in wrong place

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Very new to plotly (and having fun). This looks pretty good except that the hover doesn't show the label for the marker I am hovering over. From what I can deduce, it is only following my mouse horizontally. If I stay on the same X coord and move up and down, it will stay on the same label but not true if I move left or right on the same Y coord.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

[image: ggplotly]

This example seems to reproduce it if I put my mouse in the center of a, b, or e

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggmap)
 library(plotly)

 Philly <- map_data("county")%>% 
   filter(region=="pennsylvania", 
          subregion=="philadelphia")    

 Points <- data.frame(NAME = letters[1:6],
                      SIZE = c(15, 20, 30, 20, 15, 40),
                      X = c(-75.21, -75.23, -75.22, -75.18, -75.2, -75.2),
                      Y = c(39.9, 39.925, 39.951, 39.952, 40.025, 39.93))

 ggplotly(ggplot() + 
            geom_polygon(data = Philly, aes(long, lat, group = subregion)) + 
            geom_point(data = Points, aes(X, Y, color = NAME, size = SIZE, text=NAME))
           )
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error in match.arg(method) : object 'subregion' not found` when I try to run the code.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include the libraries. I updated the code.

Comment: can't give you a reason, but it's probably one of the many bugs between ggplot2 and plotly. If you try both geom individually they work. Put them together and it does not work.

Comment: I can't get your example to run but try adding `%>% layout(hovermode = 'closest')` after your ggplotly call.

Comment: with the newest version of ggplot2 it seems to be fixed. Thanks folks.